# scala flatMap flatten nested lists

Tags: scala, flatmap

I'm learning Scala and going through 99 Scala problems. For the following exercises:

Flatten a nested list structure.
Example:

```
scala> flatten(List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8))))
res0: List[Any] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```

The solution is given as

```
def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
  case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
  case elements => List(elements)
}
```

But I was wondering why the following does not work?

```
def flatten[A](ls: List[List[A]]): List[A] = ls flatMap {
  case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
  case elements => List(elements)
}
```

IntellJ IDEA tells me the issue is with the `flatten(ms)` part, saying "cannot resolve reference flatten with such a signature" and in the `List` class documentation for `flatten` it says "Note: The compiler might not be able to infer the type parameter".

Any ideas why the second code does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Someone else had a different question, but using the same example.

I break down each step and explain it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349449/5398254)

Comment: Yes that someone else was me! And I accepted your great detailed informative  answer, so thank you. But I feel this is different and was was not explain in that reply (I did not ask it to be explained there). Here I am asking why we cant use the [A] to say this could be of type int or char or whatever. The [A] syntax used in all the other first ten questions on 99 scala problems and when I test myself I'm finding it hard to stop myself using [A] for this example, but I need to as its wrong. But If i knew why it was wrong I may find not trying to use the [A] comes more naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Because last step of unwrapping will fail? You will have `List(elements)`, and second version of `flatten` requires providing `List` in `List`.